# Serializing QVariant through QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, qvariant

I'm possibly writing it wrong but here's the code that i'm trying to execute and it fails
to do what's expected:

```
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QVariant>
#include <iostream>


int main(){

    QByteArray data;
    QDataStream ds(&data,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QVariant v(123);
    ds << v;
    std::cout <<"test: " <<  data.data() << std::endl; // "test: 123"


    return 0;
}
```

Given the example in the documentation of the QVariant class :

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qvariant.html#type

It should serialize the value 123 correctly to the QByteArray but doesn't do so,instead it just writes out:

```
test:
```

Anybody has an idea how to fix this ?

**EDIT**

Well, maybe it was not clear but here is the original problem:

I have possibly any QVariant built-in type stored in the QVariant such as QStringList, QString , double, int , etc....

What I want is a way to serialize the QVariant to a string and restoring it without having to do it myself for each type.
As far as I know the QVariant::toString() method does not work with all types that are accepted through QVariant, and I was thinking that passing by a QDataStream could pass me a serialized version of the QVariant.

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to the answer of piotruś I was able to answer my problem.
Here's the program:

```
int main(){
    QString str;
    {
        //serialization
        QByteArray data;
        QDataStream ds(&data,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
        QVariant v(123);
        ds << v;
        data = data.toBase64();
        str = QString(data);
        cout << str.toStdString() << endl;

    }
    {
        //deserialization
        QByteArray data = str.toLatin1();
        data = QByteArray::fromBase64(data);
        QDataStream ds(&data,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QVariant v;
        ds >> v;
        cout << v.toInt() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: may be it just not print it, as data will contains more information then just 123. What is length of data ?

Comment: std::cout << data.size() << std::endl; says 9

Comment: @Lex exactly, 9, see in my answer why it is so  : p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QDataStream` does not write text, it writes binary data in the form specified [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html).  So you should not expect to see any printable characters in the byte array, and certainly not the string representation of the number.

`QTextStream` is used for writing out text, however it is not directly compatible with `QVariant`.  You would need to write your own code to test what type the variant contains and write out the appropriate string.

Comment: Aight and do you know how should I convert the QByteArray obtained through serialization to a QString ?

Comment: An If I'm not mistaken, the line std::cout <<"test: " <<  data.data() << std::endl; should print at least the binary version of the serialized QVariant, no ?

Comment: For what purpose? For debug output, you can use toHex(). Otherwise there's no way to convert arbitrary binary data to a readable string.

Comment: No, qDebug()/std::cout won't print anything sensible if the bytearray contains non-printable characters, \0 and the like.

Comment: Not for debug, just for the purpose of being able to store it into a string and restore it at another program run. I want to serialize the QVariant data to a string, serialize the string using boost::serialisation and then restore the string with boost::serialization and restore the QVariant from the data into the string. Does it make sense ? ;)

Comment: For that I'd either serialize to text directly (QTextStream, XML, Json etc.), or use base64 encoding (See QByteArray::toBase64() and QByteArray::fromBase64())

Comment: I got it working, I post solution in the original post and accept your answer as the answer to the original question! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
QByteArray data;
QDataStream dsw(&data,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QVariant v(123);
dsw << v;

QDataStream dsr(&data,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QVariant qv;
dsr>>qv;
qDebug()<<qv.toString();
```

However your data 123 is written to `QByteArray` already. The point is `QByteArray` being stored as array of `char` in memory will not show you "123" if you try to debug this but will show "{" instead which is [ASCII](http://www.google.pl/imgres?imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg&imgrefurl=http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII&h=582&w=875&sz=638&tbnid=tFDaWIkU9WcTeM%3a&tbnh=90&tbnw=136&zoom=1&usg=__TTThYKG98OLYd6myfiHzdDzP_qI=&docid=vOBp3ejzLNAQHM&sa=X&ei=VJlnUsSoLsbesgaxyYHgAg&ved=0CEoQ9QEwAw) character of code 123. You can still print this QByteArray from the raw memory. You will do it this way:

```
const char *dataPtr = data.operator const char *();
     int i=0;
     while (i<9) {
         std::cout << "[" << *dataPtr << "]";
         ++dataPtr;
         ++i;
     }
```

and the output is:
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[**{**]

you might want to do `

```
data.setByteOrder( QDataStream::LittleEndian );
```

to print bytes from stream stored in little endian order.

Comment: This answer should be selected as correct.  It provides a reasonable interpretation of the OP's question and provides a solution (as opposed to just saying you are wrong)